# Search box dropping characters after final dash

Tags: magento-1.9, search

When I search by sku that has dashes in it the characters after the last dash drops off when you hit the submit button. May I ask for direction?

Comment: Are you using any search extensions or just native Magento? Do you have any code you can show?

Comment: AMASTYS XSEARCH IS INSTALLED BUT DISABLED. TEMPLATE PATH HINTS IS CALLING BASE.